# Regex validation on decimal

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex to validate decimal numbers with dot `.`

```
/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/
```

It works fine for all the cases except the case `12.`

Working Example:

```
12
12.2
10.222
12.
```

I want to throw validation error when user enters (`12.`): at least a digit after decimal point needs to be entered (like `12.1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add one or more quantificator:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

It will match whole number: `12`, `1222`

If there is a decimal point, then there must be at least 1 digit before and after the decimal point: `1.1`, `34.2`

These cases are not allowed: `.43`, `23.`