# How do I add validation to a Griview Textbox(only numeric and Decimal)

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with contain Textbox. I want to validate this textbox with textbox keypress event

Comment: Are you using jQuery library in your application?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate through javascript.

Client side validation:
search these file and add in your project:

1. jquery.validationEngine-en.js
2. jquery.validationEngine.js
3. validationEngine.jquery.css

Then add reference to your page in script tag and css in link tag.

Give id to textbox and use `class="validate[required,custom[integer]"`, then write a script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textboxid").validationEngine('attach', { scroll: true, promptPosition: "topLeft", showOneMessage: true, autoHideDelay: 3000, autoHidePrompt: true, delay: 500 });
});
```

If you want to use server side validation then read about requiredfieldvalidator.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Validation Help ful to you below regex links available

[Regex validation on decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050798/regex-validation-on-decimal) 
  [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery library in the project then refer this function below.

```
jQuery.fn.forceNumeric = function () {
return this.each(function () {
    $(this).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && key >= 48 && key <= 57 || key >= 96 && key <= 105 || key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 || key == 35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 39 || key == 46 || key == 45) return true;

        return false;
      });
   });
}
```

Assign a `cssClass` property to `TextBox` like

```
<input name="txtAny" id="txtAny" class="customonly" />
```

And in `script tags` of page add this below line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.customonly').forceNumeric();
});
```

This will bind the event (forceNumeric) on all `TextBox` within a grid template.

For quick reference use the [<kbd>**JsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgupta17/6Enk9/1/)