# Regex preg_replace on decimal number within a link

Tags: regex, decimal

I'd like to surround the 2.5 with a span elemtent using regular expressions preg_replace. But only in the link name, not the URL.

```
<a href="mydomain.tld/2.5-Subchapter.php">2.5 Subchapter</a>
```

Anyone likes to help me with this challenge?

I did try this [Regex validation on decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050798/regex-validation-on-decimal) already, but it didn't work for me.

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to ssc-hrep3's answer below, here the answer for a PHP solution (I forgot to mention it before):

```
$myNav = preg_replace('/(>)(\d\.\d+)/s', '$1<span>$2</span>',$myNav );
```

---

Kind Regards, 
Steffano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just this simple case, you could look for the `>` character:

```
(>)(\d\.\d)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1<span>$2</span>
```

```js
var text = '<a href="mydomain.tld/2.5-Subchapter.php">2.5 Subchapter</a>';
var regex = /(>)(\d\.\d)/g;
var replacement = "$1<span>$2</span>";

var result = text.replace(regex, replacement);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ssc-hrep3